# How to reduce line length in search results?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to only show the file name in the search results instead of the full path? By default it shows the full file path followed by the actual line.

If it did, I could make the results window take less space on the screen and wouldn't have to bother with scrolling to see the actual line (yes, the full paths are quite long).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, although involves registry hack:

- go to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find`
- create a new string `Find result format` with value `$f$e($l,$c):$t\r\n`
- enjoy

---

Here are [the values you can use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/03/customize-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-the-find-results-window.aspx) in the string:

**Files**

- `$p`      path
- `$f`      filename
- `$v`      drive/unc share
- `$d`      dir
- `$n`      name
- `$e`      .ext

**Location**

- `$l`      line
- `$c`      col
- `$x`      end col if on first line, else end of first line
- `$L`      span end line
- `$C`      span end col

**Text**

- `$0`      matched text
- `$t`      text of first line
- `$s`      summary of hit
- `$T`     text of spanned lines

**Char**

- `\n`      newline
- `\s`      space
- `\t`      tab
- `\\`      slash
- `\$`      $

Comment: @andreister: any way to limit the maximum number of characters shown per result line?